# Invoking generic extension method with parameters

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, .net-core, .net-standard

Consider the following extension method:

```
public static class ValiDoc
{
        public static IEnumerable<RuleDescription> GetRules<T>(this AbstractValidator<T> validator, bool documentNested = false)
        {
             //....
        }
}
```

An implementation of AbstractValidator:

```
public class AddressValidator : AbstractValidator<Address>
{
    public AddressValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(address => address.HouseNumber).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(address => address.StreetName).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(address => address.PostCode).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

I want to invoke the GetRules() extension method on ValiDoc via reflection and pass in an instance of AddressValidator as the first parameter, with a boolean for the second.

Having never played with Reflection before I am pretty overwhelmed, however by following the examples available here I have made *some* progress.

```
//Parameter 1
Type type = typeof(AbstractValidator<>);

// Instance of Address
Type constructed = type.MakeGenericType(childValidator.ValidatorType.GetTypeInfo().BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);

// Find the extension method based on the signature I have defined for the usage
// public static IEnumerable<RuleDescription> GetRules<T>(this AbstractValidator<T> validator, bool documentNested = false)
var runtimeMethods = typeof(ValiDoc).GetRuntimeMethods();

MethodInfo generatedGetRules = null;

// Nothing fancy for now, just pick the first option as we know it is GetRules
using (IEnumerator<MethodInfo> enumer = runtimeMethods.GetEnumerator())
{
    if (enumer.MoveNext()) generatedGetRules = enumer.Current;
}

// Create the generic method instance of GetRules()
generatedGetRules = generatedGetRules.MakeGenericMethod(constructed);

//Parameter 1 = Derived from AbstractValidator<T>, Parameter 2 = boolean
var parameterArray = new object[] { childValidator.GetValidator(new PropertyValidatorContext(new ValidationContext(rule.Member.DeclaringType), rule, propertyName)), true };

//Invoke extension method with validator instance
generatedGetRules.Invoke(null, parameterArray);
```

When executing generatedGetRules.Invoke, I receive the following error message:

> 'Object of type 'ValiDoc.Tests.TestData.Validators.AddressValidator'
>   cannot be converted to type
>   'FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1[FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1[ValiDoc.Tests.TestData.POCOs.Address]]'.'

Have I missed anything obvious? I can't tell if I am nearly there or miles away.

**Supporting values:**

typeof(AbstractValidator<>) = {FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1[T]}

childValidator.ValidatorType.GetTypeInfo().BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[0] = {ValiDoc.Tests.TestData.POCOs.Address}

constructed = {FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1[ValiDoc.Tests.TestData.POCOs.Address]}

generatedGetRules = {System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ValiDoc.Output.RuleDescription] GetRules[AbstractValidator`1](FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1[FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1[ValiDoc.Tests.TestData.POCOs.Address]], Boolean)}

Parameter array = {ValiDoc.Tests.TestData.Validators.AddressValidator}, boolean

***EDIT:***
Working implementation:

```
// Find the extension method based on the signature I have defined for the usage
                // public static IEnumerable<RuleDescription> GetRules<T>(this AbstractValidator<T> validator, bool documentNested = false)
                var runtimeMethods = typeof(ValiDoc).GetRuntimeMethods();

                MethodInfo generatedGetRules = null;

                // Nothing fancy for now, just pick the first option as we know it is GetRules
                using (IEnumerator<MethodInfo> enumer = runtimeMethods.GetEnumerator())
                {
                    if (enumer.MoveNext()) generatedGetRules = enumer.Current;
                }

                // Create the generic method instance of GetRules()
                generatedGetRules = generatedGetRules.MakeGenericMethod(childValidator.ValidatorType.GetTypeInfo().BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);

                //Parameter 1 = Derived from AbstractValidator<T>, Parameter 2 = boolean
                var parameterArray = new object[] { childValidator.GetValidator(new PropertyValidatorContext(new ValidationContext(rule.Member.DeclaringType), rule, propertyName)), true };

                //Invoke extension method with validator instance
                var output = generatedGetRules.Invoke(null, parameterArray) as IEnumerable<RuleDescription>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your error message, I see `AddressValidator` (`AbstractValidator<Address>`) can't be converted to `AbstractValidator<AbstractValidator<Address>>`, which is exactly what you're doing. Constructed is **not** what you want to pass into MakeGenericMethod, I'm assuming, since the method is generic on T, but the first argument is `this AbstractValidator<T>` so you're getting a double generic specialization instead of what you want.

Comment: Nailed it - question updated with answer.

Many thanks for your help :)